# Fix a csv with HTML content in rows with Python

Tags: python, csv, format

I have a problem with a csv :

[CSV image problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iDPE.png)

I have HTML code in a csv but in some rows, the code broke the csv format.

I would like to know if somebody know how to solve this problem with python.

I would to fix the csv to get this format.

[csv with format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkSgn.png)

I try to use **with open** and **pandas** to create a new csv

```
import csv
with open('csv_problem.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: From the image, if the HTML were properly escaped, it'd all be contained in one cell, but it's not. Once the CSV is broken like that, the only thing to do is fix it: either fix the process/program that created it; or go in and fix those cells by hand.